# Compute subform total

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a sub form that looks like a datasheet view. It returns prices from a query I made. Essentially I want to compute the total of those prices using vba. I just do not know how to get all the prices and put them into an array.

Here is a picture to get a better idea:
[image]

I want Compute Total to compute the total.

The record source for the sub form is:

```
SELECT [Rental Query].[CopyNo], [Rental Query].[RentalNo], [Rental Query].[Title], [Rental Query].[Format], [Rental Query].[DaysRented], [Rental Query].[Price] FROM [Rental Query];
```

I'm interested in the Price. The query uses a specific formula to create that field.

What I want is to be able to get all the prices and sum them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a textbox to the form footer and set it to:

```
=Sum(MyField)
```

You will not be able to see the control in datasheet view, but you can refer to it on the main form in a textbox:

```
=MySubformControl.Form.MySumControl
```

Comment: Either type the line into the textbox in design view, substituting your field name(s), type it into the control source property, or use the Expression Builder for the control source - the three dots.